# How to draw an isosceles trapezium with perpendicular diagonals

Tags: geometry

Can you explain me how to draw an isosceles trapezium with perpendicular diagonals?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What else is given?

Comment: We have to prove that P is the middle of AD.

https://imgur.com/a/FBaoJIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by drawing two perpendicular lines. Then draw two circles, with different radii, with centers at the intersection of the two lines. In the big circle choose two adjacent intersection with the two lines. On the small circle choose the intersections on the other side of the center.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what to do after I made the two circles with different radii, with centers at the intersection of two lines. By the way my English isn't very good. Sorry!

Comment: I've put a quick drawing of what I have in mind. The angles between the parallel sides and the diagonals are $45^\circ$. If you know what angle the sides make, you can also calculate the ratios of the radii.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Can I ask someone why I have -2 rating on the post? What is the problem?

Comment: Some people (not me) seems to think that you did not show effort, or that the question is not interesting. Usually it happens when people ask "Solve this problem for me". In this case, I disagree. I think that it's a nice conceptual question.

Comment: Thank you so much!